# Slow Google Maps Navigation Launching on Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, async-await, geolocation

In my application Users can launch navigation consisting of current position and destination displaying on google maps app.

The code is the following:

```dart
 ListTile(
                    title:
                        Text("Launch Google Maps", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
                          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);

                      print("Position:  $position"); //all Information about position (Coordinates etc.)

                      List<Placemark> placemark =
                          await Geolocator().placemarkFromPosition(position);

                      print("Placemark: ${placemark[0].locality}"); //Kingston
                      final String clubName =
                          clubs[index].name.toString().replaceAll(" ", "+");
                      print("Name: $clubName"); //Flawless
                      final String clubCity =
                          clubs[index].location.city.toString().replaceAll("ü", "ue");
                      print("Stadt: $clubCity");//London
                      final String newGoogleUrl =
                          "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=${placemark[0].locality}&destination=$clubName,$clubCity";

                      if (await canLaunch(newGoogleUrl)) {
                        await launch(newGoogleUrl);
                      } else {
                        throw 'Could not launch $newGoogleUrl';
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

Code flow:

- List item
- get Users current position
- get place details based on the position
- get club name
- get club city
- compose URL string
- launch google maps based on URL

Everything is just working fine. I can get all the required information and launch google maps at the end. But the biggest problem here ist, that this take about 8 seconds till launching google maps. I know it is an async function and I have to await the positions etc. but I don't know how else to solve this.

How can I improve this code to launch google maps almost instantly without having to wait 8 seconds always after pressing the button?

I thought about storing the current location in shared preferences, so I do not need to call the Geolocator API, but I'm not sure about this approach in regards to how often to update that position etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Beside making it [async](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28493#issuecomment-509001212), have you tried the lite version of google maps? 
[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0N1Xkc_1pU&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers)
It's suitable if your map has a lot of marker, or just to simply increase performance in exchange of fancy animation.
In flutter, set the lite mode to true

```
return GoogleMap(
  liteModeEnabled: true,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: _initialLocation,
    zoom: 17,
  ),
  markers: _markers,
  polylines: _lines,
);
```